# functional inequality and uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

i'm solving a problem in the book "Problems in mathematical analysis".

A function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous at zero and $f(0)= 0$ and $f(x_{1}+ x_{2})\le f(x_{1})+f(x_{2})$ for any $x_{1}, x_{2}\in \mathbb R.$

Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$

If $f$ was non-negative function, it would be a lot easier. But, without that assumption, I'm having difficulty in properly changing the inequality $|f(x_{1}) - f(x_{2})|$.

If you give me some hint, I would appreciate that. Thank you for reading.

Comment: use the continuity at zero and functional inequality to get $|f(x+y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ where $|y|<\delta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the continuity at zero for $\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $$|f(0)=|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$$ whenever $|x-0|<\delta$.
Now for $x\in \Bbb{R}$ and $|y|<\delta$ we have by sub additivity of $f$ $$f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y) \implies f(x+y)-f(x)\le f(y)<\epsilon$$ and similarly $$f(x)=f(x+y-y)\le f(x+y)+f(-y) \implies f(x)-f(x+y) \le f(-y)<\epsilon$$ thus we get $|f(x+y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x+y-x|<\delta$ and thus $f$ is uniform conitnuous on $\Bbb{R}$